# When to prefer gensym over make-symbol in Lisp

Tags: lisp

Is there a case where gensym's feature of appending unique numbers to the prefix comes in handy? I don't get why there is `gensym` when

```
(let ((str "batman"))
  (eq (make-symbol str)
      (make-symbol str)))
```

always returns `nil`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GENSYM for example makes debugging generated code slightly easier.

Example:

See this expansion of a LOOP macro. You can see which symbols are the same by looking at their names, even though they are not interned in a package. There are two uninterned temp variables. Different names now make the use clear.

```
CL-USER 4 > (pprint (macroexpand '(loop for i in '(1 2 3) sum i)))

(BLOCK NIL
  (MACROLET ((LOOP-FINISH () '(GO #:|end-loop-1103|)))
    (LET ((I NIL) (#:|tail-1106| '(1 2 3)) (#:|by-1107| 'SYSTEM:CDR$CONS))
      (LET ((#:|accumulator-1104| 0))
        (DECLARE (TYPE NUMBER #:|accumulator-1104|))
        (TAGBODY
         #:|begin-loop-1102| NIL
                 (PROGN
                   (WHEN (OR (ENDP #:|tail-1106|)) (GO #:|end-loop-1103|))
                   (LET ((#:|temp-1109| (FUNCALL #:|by-1107| #:|tail-1106|))
                         (#:|temp-1108| (SYSTEM:CAR$CONS #:|tail-1106|)))
                     (SETQ I #:|temp-1108|)
                     (SETQ #:|tail-1106| #:|temp-1109|)))
                 (INCF #:|accumulator-1104| I)
                 (GO #:|begin-loop-1102|)
         #:|end-loop-1103| (RETURN-FROM NIL #:|accumulator-1104|))))))
```